# Shared VPN on home server

Tags: networking, macos, vpn

I am looking into getting a VPN service, something like NORDvpn or similar but I want to run the app on my Mac server and route all my internet traffic from my MacBookPro's, Sky Q box, iPhone's etc through the Mac server.

1. Is this possible ?
2. Where can I find some info on how to do this ?
3. Is this the best way ?
4. Open to other options or ideas ?

I have tried to find some info online but most of it is based around Windows or Linux.

EDIT
My Mac server is a MacPro 2,1 which has 2 NIC ports and I have a 16 port un-managed switch which connects all the devices. I could have internet ethernet cable directly to one port and send other port to the switch and have the VPN in the middle

Comment: Do you want all your traffic to use the VPN?, if so I would suggest finding a VPN service you can use with a router (and possibly buying a router that will allow you to use VPN's if yours currently does not support this.) this would be a much easier approach.

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to buy a new router as I currently have a Google Home wifi router and it does the job well but it doesnt offer a VPN option I dont believe

Comment: Do exactly as you were thinking: LAN -> Switch -> Mac server (NIC 1) -> Mac server (NIC2) -> Google router. Connect the Mac server to the NordVPN. Install a proxy server on the Mac server and configure it to use the NordVPN interface as its WAN/external connection. If you make it a transparent proxy then your devices will use it with minimal configuration Alternatively, you could add yet another machine into the equation and install the likes of pfSense that can natively connect to NordVPN's OpenVPN service: https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

You could consider adding a low cost router that supports VPN as a gateway between your Google Home router and your internet modem.

Comment: Could I not do this using my current server as it just sits there and has 2 NIC's on it ?

Comment: You absolutely could, but unless you're using the server for other purposes, I wouldn't consider it the most efficient or effective device for 'simply' managing a VPN server.